# why can't we set doctrine's connection from the inverse side

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Everywhere, I read that whe cannot set the connection from the reverse side, but With this kind of code, couldn't wee?

```
class Article
{
    private $tags;

    public function addTag(Tag $tag, $bothSide = true)
    {
        if ($bothSide) {
            $tag->addArticle($this, false); 
        }
        $this->tags[] = $tag;
    }
}

class Tag
{
    private $articles;

    public function addArticle(Article $article, $bothSide = true)
    {
        if ($bothSide) {
            $article->addTag($this, false); 
        }
        $this->articles[] = $article;
    }
}
```

By using a simple `$bothSide` var, it should work so I can't understand why it is not the recommended way to go, could you telle me, please?

PS : I'm using the documentation's code has starting point (http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional)

Comment: Article owns the relation because you are most likely to create a new article and set its tags than create a tag and set it's article. You can set the relation the other way and I don't see why you need `$bothSide` here !? What do you mean by **set doctrine's connection from the inverse side**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @mickdev... it's not clear what you mean by **set doctrine's connection from the inverse side**. You can set parameters on either owner's side or inverse side, but when it's time to persist the changes in the database doctrine will only check the owning side. Something like your code can help make sure that owning side is always set, but make sure you don't create an infinite loop. I think that's what you are doing with the $bothSides parameter, although somewhat awkardly. The code below is a little cleaner in my opinion. This assumes Article is the owning side in the ManyToMany relationship you are setting up.

```
class Article
{
    private $tags;

    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->tags = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function addTag(Tag $tag)
    {
        if ($this->tags->contains($tag) {
            return;
        }

        $this->tags[] = $tag;

        // Set the inverse side
        // Since Article is the owning side, 
        // this is not mandatory, 
        // but may be useful depending on your application
        $tag->addArticle($this);
    }
}

class Tag
{
    private $articles;

    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->tags = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function addArticle(Article $article)
    {
        if ($this->articles->contains($article) {
            return;
        }

        $this->articles[] = $article;

        // persist the owning side
        // this is mandatory to persist the change
        $article->addTag($this); 
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, so, only the inverse side has to set the relation in both entities! I didn't got this! Are you sure? because I Read a lot of contradictory thing, like [this french MOOC](https://openclassrooms.com/courses/developpez-votre-site-web-avec-le-framework-symfony/les-relations-entre-entites-avec-doctrine2-1#/id/r-3622755) wich says that (I synthetize + translate) : 

You have to choose a side (proprietary or inverse) and always use this side to set the relation. On this side, you have to apply the relation on both entities using `$article->addTag($this, false);  $this->articles[] = $article;`

Comment: Yes. See this page, read it carefully. It has lots of good information on this subject. See especially section 11.2.  http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html

Comment: Thank you, I had tested this but was failing because of something else : the form of the inverse side contain an EntityType of the owning side. The changes wasn't persisted in base until I set by_reference to false in order to use the setter. (By default, doctrine use the reflection API to set the values)